# How to mock pathlib.Path.read_text for a particular file

Tags: python, python-unittest

The unittest docs show you [how to use mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.mock_open) to mock *direct* calls to `builtins.open`.

But how about mocking `pathlib`'s `read_text` like this:

```py
import pathlib

pathlib.Path("/path/to/file").read_text()
```

Using the recipe in the unittest docs doesn't patch this correctly? It must use `builtins.open` under the hood somewhere but where??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch `pathlib.Path.read_text` directly. You only need to keep a reference to the original method, so you can decide whether to return a "fake" value, or execute the original method.

```
import pathlib
from unittest.mock import patch


path_to_mock = "foo/bar"
original_read_text = pathlib.Path.read_text

def read_text_side_effect(self: pathlib.Path, *args, **kwargs):
    # how you compare the paths depends on your use case.
    if self.absolute() == pathlib.Path(path_to_mock).absolute():
        return "mocked text"
    else:
        return original_read_text(self, *args, **kwargs)

with patch("pathlib.Path.read_text", autospec=True) as mock_read:
    mock_read.side_effect = read_text_side_effect

    print(pathlib.Path(path_to_mock).read_text())
    print(pathlib.Path("real_file").read_text())
```

Assuming "real_file" exists, you should see "mocked text" and the file's content in the output.

Comment: This is much clearer than my effort. I'm not sure about the use of the name `self` outside of a class though. Not sure if there's a standard way to refer to this positional arg outside of a class method.

Comment: I've not used `autospec=True` before, but it's required here in the mock definition to get the Path to be sent to the first positional argument of `read_text_side_effect`.

Comment: You're essentially replacing a method with that function, so it makes sense to use naming conventions for methods. In my opinion, using `self` in combination with the type hint makes it very obvious that this function will replace a method of `Path`, even before seeing the actual patch statement. You can of course name it however you like.

Comment: Autospec is required because you're patching the class method, not the resulting bound method on the object. `patch` will detect that when autospeccing and do the right thing. You could alternatively pass the replacement function to `patch` as the `new` parameter, which would directly replace the method without a mock object in between. However, you won't be able to inspect method calls and you won't be able to autospec. You should always spec your mocks/patches, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a catchall for every situation but I've had some success with this by patching `pathlib._NormalAccessor.open`.

Since `_NormalAccessor` is a "private" method, the usual caveats apply about this not being a reliable public interface and that it might change at any moment.

Having said that, here's a recipe for making it work:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
from pathlib import Path

def mock_pathlib_open_side_effect(path_glob: str, response: str):
    def _mock_path(*args, **kwargs):
        if args[0].match(path_glob):
            return mock_open(read_data=response)()

        return open(*args, **kwargs)

    return _mock_path

with patch(
    "pathlib._NormalAccessor.open",
    side_effect=mock_pathlib_open_side_effect(path_glob="*/path/to/file", response="hello world"),
):
    assert Path("/path/to/file").read_text() == "hello world"
```

This still leaves real calls to `Path.read_text()` working as normal.

Comment: Note that this does not work from Python 3.11 onwards - `pathlib` does no more use accessors since that version.